# How to add dynamic defval as an input in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Ltp = input(title="Price", defval=15923, minval=1)

Here I want to add defval as dynamic based on the chart, when we switch other chart the last day closing price needs to be set automatically..

Is there any way to achieve this in pine script.

Note: defval should be dynamic (previous day close price / last Friday close price)

Answer (score 0):

No, `defval` of the `input` can be assigned only to a constant value known at the compile time of the script.

Comment: is there anyway, i want to get previous day close value for each chart.. based on that i want to do some calculations

Comment: To call a data from another timeframe (daily close for ex) use the security() function.

Comment: i tried it, but when chart loads it should take the previous day close value and next user can give input value.. then value should take from the input